# Enlive Predefined selector-steps

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to use Enlive to clone the replace-me script tag in this html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
[...]
    <script src="/js/libs/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="replace-me"></script>
  </head>
[...]
```

**Question 1)**

I'm struggling to figure out what the "idiomatic" selector for the last script element is. Currently I'm using

```
(h/select tpl [:head :> [h/last-of-type :script]])
```

is that correct?

**Question 2)**

I have this snippet to transform the entire head entity:

```
(h/defsnippet head "templates/base.html" [:head]
  [{:keys [scripts]}]
  [h/root :> [h/last-of-type :script]]
  (h/clone-for [script scripts]
               (h/set-attr :src (:src script))))
```

Is this the correct usage of the root selector-step? I'm assuming that within the context of defsnippet, root is referencing the [:head] selector, is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This works in this case, but you might prefer `attr-has`:

   ```
   (h/select tpl [[:script (h/attr-has :src "replace-me")]])

   (h/defsnippet head "templates/base.html" [:head]
     [{:keys [scripts]}]
     [h/root :> (h/attr-has :src "replace-me")]
     (h/clone-for [script scripts]
                  (h/set-attr :src (:src script))))
   ```

   In more complex cases you could define your own selectors. Here it's unnecessary because of `attr-has`, but for the sake of example:

   ```
   (def my-pred (h/pred #(= #{"replace.me"} (h/attr-values % :src))))

   (h/defsnippet head "templates/base.html" [:head]
     [{:keys [scripts]}]
     [h/root :> my-pred]
     (clone-for [script scripts]
                (h/set-attr :src (:src script))))
   ```
2. You can use `emit*` to check whether your snippets produce the desired results:

   ```
   (apply println (h/emit* (head {:scripts [{:src "bar.js"}]})))
   ```

Comment: So my assumption about h/root when used with defsnippet is correct?

Comment: Yes, `root` matches the element matched by the selector specified in the snippet's definition. You could define a snippet with a selector matching multiple elements; in that case, each one would be matched by `root`.